# Finding the domain of an equation and then solving.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find domain and then solve:

$$\frac{x+2}{6x} +1 = \frac{x-7}{x}$$

Hello everyone, what does domain in this context mean? I'm not looking for the answer to this question. I'm just looking for a push in the right direction.

Comment: The domain means the set of values that can be substituted for $x$ without making the terms undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when we deal with expression in the form

$$\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}$$

we always need that $B(x)\neq 0$ because the division by zero is not defined.

Therefore in that case we need for the existence that $x\neq 0$ then, keeping in mind that condition, we can multiply both sides by $6x$ to obtain

$$\frac{x+2}{6x} +1 = \frac{x-7}{x}\iff x+2 +6x = 6(x-7)$$

from here we can solve for $x\neq 0$.